In the flow equation in Lecture 9 from Susskind’s ‘Classical Mechanics’, why is there a negative sign? Why is there partial and regular derivatives?
Lecture 9 of Susskind’s ‘Classical Mechanics’ has a section titled ‘Flow and Divergence’ (pages 165-167). The section discusses flow in a box with side lengths $dx$, $dy$ and $dz$. He says that if the flow velocity $v_x$ in the $x$ direction varies across the box, then the net flow into the box in the $x$ direction (across two faces) will be proportional to $-\frac{\partial v_x}{\partial x}dxdydz$. The same applies for the $y$ direction and $z$ direction. Why is there a negative at the start of the expression? Is that specifically for divergence or does it apply to convergence as well?
He states that the net flow into the box must equal the sum of these expressions. Did Susskind mistakenly state proportionality for the flow in the $x$ direction (instead of saying equals)?
I understand why the flow equation for the $x$ direction includes $dydz$ (because the number of molecules per unit time coming across the face equals the flow velocity multiplied by the area of the face ($N_x = v_x A = v_x dydz$)). I don’t understand why the dx is included (maybe to make the expression have no unit?) I also don’t understand the combination of partial and normal derivatives. Would the $\partial x$ cancel with the $dx$?


He says that if the flow velocity $v_x$ in the $x$ direction varies across the box, then the net flow into the box in the $x$ direction (across two faces) will be proportional to $-\frac{\partial v_x}{\partial x}dxdydz$.

Consider, for example, the mass of fluid flowing into and out of the box at fixed density.
The amount of mass going into the box in time $\delta t$ on the side at location x is:
$$
+\rho v_x(x) \delta t \delta y\delta z\;,\tag{A}
$$
The amount of mass going out of the box (or, "into" with a negative sign) in time $\delta t$ on the side at location $x + \delta x$ is:
$$
-\rho v_x(x+\delta x) \delta t \delta y\delta z\;,\tag{B}
$$

Why is there a negative at the start of the expression? Is that specifically for divergence or does it apply to convergence as well?

So, adding Eq. (A) and (B), the net amount of mass going into the box at time $\delta t$ is:
$$
-\rho v_x(x_0+\delta x) \delta t \delta y\delta z\;,
+\rho v_x(x_0) \delta t \delta y\delta z
$$
$$
\approx -\rho (v_x(x_0) + \delta x\frac{\partial v_x}{\partial x} - v_x(x_0))\delta t\delta y\delta x
$$
$$
=-\rho \frac{\partial v_x}{\partial x} \delta x\delta y\delta z \delta t\;.
$$
So, dividing by $\delta t$ to get mass flow rate gives:
$$
-\rho \frac{\partial v_x}{\partial x} \delta x\delta y\delta z
$$
